# Can I host my own database in Commercetools platform?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, saas, paas, commercetools

It is possible in magento where I can set my inhouse database at localhost. Can I do the same with commercetools?

I do not like to share my data with commercetools, but I still want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The commercetools platform is a PaaS. There is no way for clients to install the database on their localhost. You cannot make use of the platform's commerce features if you don't provide the platform with data.

What is your concern with sharing your data with commercetools? Although the commercetools platform is a multi-tenant PaaS, your project's data is well isolated from any other project on the platform. The access to your data is protected by OAuth2.

Comment: As our client is having their own licenced database,and since they have paid for the database, they are not ready to move their data. But as they are facing some issues with their existing system and also they liked commercetools features, so they only want to use commercetools API's by keeping their catalog as it is.

Comment: Also I want to know which are the API's I can use without sharing my product and users data?

Answer (score 2):

Commercetools manages data for you. It is a feature rich platform where large enterprise customers or even medium scale systems can easily adopt and use the latest technologies.

Commercetools maintains non-relational databases which are more flexible. If you are looking to use your own database, I doubt that commercetools platform would suits your needs. Maybe typical ERP solution would work. But you need will definitely miss the latest technical advancements and flexibility that comes with microservices.